# Errors in ploting time in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, plot

I plotted a relationship between some variables and time.
Time is located in the matrix; section below:

```
> 19.997777777777774
  19.998055555555560
  19.998333333333338
  19.998611111111117
  19.998888888888892
```

It's UTC time (time lapse: 1 hour, interval: 1 second) after conversion on hours with decimal places.

The figure I acquired seems to have errors:
[image: changes of latitude in time]

Can it be caused by some common reason I haven't noticed?
Thank you.

Update:

```
h=nmea/10000; 
h_int = floor(h); 
h_dec = h - h_int;

m = h_dec * 100; 
m_int = floor(m);
m_dec = m - m_int;

s = m_dec * 100;

time= h_int + m_int/60 + s/3600;
```

referential nmea: [195955 195956 195957 195958 195959]

Comment: Can you post the code you used for plotting?

Comment: plot(time,data1,time,data2)

Comment: and the code you used for converting time to decimal hours?

Comment: I appended it to an update to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the way that you defined the residue of the minutes.
If you'll run your code while the change of the minutes, you'll get the problem. Here you can see the "jump" in the third value (-a round minute) in `s`, that cause the jump in `time`:

```
nmea=[195858 195859 195900 195901 195902]
h=nmea/10000; 
h_int = floor(h); 
h_dec = h - h_int;
m = h_dec * 100; 
m_int = floor(m);
m_dec = m - m_int;
s = m_dec * 100
time= h_int + m_int/60 + s/3600

s =

   58.0000   59.0000  100.0000    1.0000    2.0000


time =

   19.9828   19.9831   19.9944   19.9836   19.9839
```

For shorter and right way, you can use `mod` function:

```
nmea=[195858 195859 195900 195901 195902];
m_int=(mod(nmea,10000)-mod(nmea,100))/100;
s=mod(nmea,100);
time= h_int + m_int/60 + s/3600
time =

   19.9828   19.9831   19.9833   19.9836   19.9839
```